# Reactive WebSocketSession not able to retrieve .closeStatus when connection finishes on doOnComplete or doOnCancel

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm trying to retrieve the 'WebSocketSession.closeStatus()'
I refer here to this object: org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketSession.

I have tried to retrieve it during the:

````
 **doOnComplete
 doOnCancel
 doOnTerminate**

Using the code below:

    ```.doOnComplete(() ->{

        webSocketSession.closeStatus().map(x -> {

            log.info(x.getReason());
            log.info(x.getCode());

        });
                    
    })```       

 The code is executed, but nothing is printed.

 I did the same for ```.doOnCancel(()-> { webSocketSession.closeStatus()```

 The client is a mobile app, some times the client app closes appropriately, sometimes it doesn't. And I need to capture the code.

 Thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the returned `Mono<CloseStatus>` i.e.

```
.doOnComplete(() ->{

    webSocketSession.closeStatus().map(x -> {

        log.info(x.getReason());
        log.info(x.getCode());

    }).subscribe();
                
})
```